# Forcing the dash in French initials in bibliography

Tags: bibtex, french

How one writes "Smith, J.-M.," in bibliography? I want the dash not to disappear! If I write the full name, e.g. Jean-Michel Smith, then BibTeX treats it properly and generates Smith, J.-M.

I have tried Smith, J.-M., Smith, J.{-}M.

If you wonder why, in some cases I dont know what the initial stands for, and still prefer to respect the formatting of names.

Comment: Which bibliography style do you use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the bibliography style abbreviates names, then using

```
author={Sartre, Jean-Paul},
```

is sufficient. If you want to have an abbreviated name anyway, then

```
author={Sartre, {J.-P.}},
```

will do.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{a,
 author={Sartre, {J.-P.}},
 title={La naus{\'e}e},
 year=1938,
 publisher={Gallimard},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\cite{a}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't have enough "credit" to vote it up, thanks!